# Do you create the Aggregate Object when you instantiate a Root Entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Or do you define a new object that contains the Root Entity object among others?

```
public class SomeAggregateName()
{
   public EntityRoot root {get;set;}
   public Entity entity {get;set;}
}
```

OR  Is this the Aggregate implied?

```
public class EntityRoot()
{ 
   public Entity entity {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Anything that you're not sure of with the answer below? I'm happy to clarify if need be.

Answer (score 3):

The aggregate is implied usually - ie, it is the Entity.

Your example makes it a little harder to follow because you haven't actually got a domain.

But let's take a classic example of an Order Aggregate Root, that contains OrderLines. The Order is an Entity - it is also the Aggregate Root. The OrderLine is contained within the Order Aggregate, so cannot be accessed directly outside of the Order Aggregate.

```
// This is the Order Aggregate Root
public class Order
{
    private IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A related question:

if I want to use FluentNHiberanate, for example, to initialize my domain entities it requires that my Order class look like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

this violates the encapsulation of the aggregate's internal entities.
Any ideas on how to do it without breaking the encapsulation?

---

OK found it (one of the available solutions),
change OrderLines member to private and add this to the mapping file:

```
HasMany(Reveal.Property<Order, IEnumerable<OrderLine>>("OrderLines"))
.Inverse()
.Cascade
.All();
```